# How to create a multi-dimensional array from string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Looking to create a multi-dimensional array from a string. My string is:

13,4,3|65,1,1|27,3,2

I want to store it in an array which I'm assuming would look like this:

```
$multi_array = array
  (
  array(13,4,3),
  array(65,1,1),
  array(27,3,2)
  );
```

So I can call it with $multi_array[1][1], which should return "4".

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$string = "13,4,3|65,1,1|27,3,2";
$explode = explode("|", $string);
$multi_array = array(); //declare array

  $count = 0;

foreach ($explode as $value) {

  $explode2 = explode(",", $value);

  foreach ($explode2 as $value2) {
    // I'm stuck here....don't know what to do.
  }
  $count++;
}
echo '<pre>', print_r($multi_array), '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way,

```
$data = '13,4,3|65,1,1|27,3,2';

$return_2d_array = array_map (
  function ($_) {return explode (',', $_);},
  explode ('|', $data)
);

print '<pre>';
print_r ($return_2d_array);
print '</pre>';
```

**OR** with your own code

```
$string = "13,4,3|65,1,1|27,3,2";
$explode = explode("|", $string);
$multi_array = array(); //declare array

$count = 0;

foreach ($explode as $key=>$value) { // see changes on this line

  $explode2 = explode(",", $value);

  foreach ($explode2 as $value2) {
    $multi_array[$key][$count] = $value2;
    $count++; // see count variable position changes here
  }

}
echo '<pre>', print_r($multi_array), '</pre>';
```

Comment: Wow! So fast. Thanks so much for your answer Charlie, or is it Mac...or Deandra?   Anyway, much appreciated :) It won't let me accept your answer yet, cause you answered too fast.

Answer (score 3):

Your outer `foreach` loop is correct. You don't need your inner loop though as `explode` returns an array. Just append this array to your result array and you'll get a 2D array

```
$input = "13,4,3|65,1,1|27,3,2";

$result = [];

foreach (explode('|', $input) as $split)
    $result[] = explode(',', $split);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **explode** function to split a string with a delimiter, in this case `'|'`, like this:

PHP:

```
$data = '13,4,3|65,1,1|27,3,2';

$new_arrays = explode('|', $data); // with this you can separate the string in 3 arrays with the demiliter '|'
```

Here is the documentation of explode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Regards!